# Listing appendix entries separately

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have two chapters in the appendix - tables and figures( "Appendix A Figures" and Appendix B Tables"), i want the TOC of the document to show the entries in each. For example, "A.1 This is some figure". I have no idea how to do this. Currently only the Appendix A and B are listed in the TOC.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents



\begin{appendices}


\captionsetup[table]{list=no}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\chapter{Tables \label{app:figures}}
\begin{table}
\caption{Test table one}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test table one}
\end{table}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can combine the list of tables and tables of contents by telling LaTeX to use the same extension for the lists.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\def\ext@figure{toc}
\def\ext@table{toc}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents



\begin{appendices}


%\captionsetup[table]{list=no}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\chapter{Tables \label{app:figures}}
\begin{table}
\caption{Test table one}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test table two}
\end{table}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Small problem with this solution - it made the content of my list of tables and list of figures (the one that are from the body of the text, not from the appendix) disappear.

Comment: You didn't say you had figures in the body _and_ the appendix:-) Just move the four lines makeatletter...makeatother to the start of the appendix so normal figures get written to lof and appendix ones get written to toc (is that really what you want??)

Comment: Awesome, it works exactly the way I want it. Sorry for forgetting to clarify about the two lists. It's a weird academic requirement, to only include in the lot and lof things from the main body.